# Python. Parsing XML: getting separated values of attributes as a list

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Here's the thing:

```
<parent>  
  <child attribute1="100" attribute2="1,2"/>
  <child attribute1="200" attribute2="1,2,5"/>  
  <child attribute1="300" attribute2="1,2,5,10"/>  
</parent>
```

What I'd like to see after parsing it:

```
100 [1, 2] 
200 [1, 2, 5]  
300 [1, 2, 5, 10]
```

as lists.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply split the attribute values and convert them to integers, per element.

With [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.fromstring(example)

for child in tree.findall('.//child'):
    attribute1 = int(child.attrib['attribute1'])
    attribute2 = [int(v) for v in child.attrib['attribute2'].split(',')]
    print attribute1, attribute2
```

For your example document, this prints out:

```
>>> for child in tree.findall('.//child'):
...     attribute1 = int(child.attrib['attribute1'])
...     attribute2 = [int(v) for v in child.attrib['attribute2'].split(',')]
...     print attribute1, attribute2
... 
100 [1, 2]
200 [1, 2, 5]
300 [1, 2, 5, 10]
```

Comment: `find_all` should be `findall` :)

Comment: Ah! okay. Made it work. Just '.parse' instead of 'fromstring'. Thank you very much.

Comment: @meenauh: I used `fromstring` here because I had your example text in a python string, but `.parse()` is indeed what you need for a file.